# WFFM - Email Body Inserted Value from Drop list Should be the Display Text, Not the Hidden Value

Tags: wffm

I have a several fields that are of type "Drop list". The fields are added to the body of the "Send Email Editor" email.

In Sitecore 7.5, the email body was getting the displayed text on the drop list. Now that we upgraded to Sitecore 8.1, the email body is getting the hidden value of the drop list.

I need the displayed text, not the hidden value.

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but the drop list is being populated with metadata. In terms of the metadata, the value I want displayed in the email body is the Title. But, the value is being displayed instead.

The problem is that the values are coded and not useful to the people getting the emails.

Sitecore Version - 8.1 rev. 160519 (Update-3)

WFFM Version - 8.1 rev. 160523

**Send Email Editor:**

[image]

**HTML From Email Editor:**

```
<p>Province China: [<label id="{A7421C76-8AAF-4782-865B-42868AF7AA48}">Province_China</label>]<br />
<em>default: Anhui</em></p>
```

**Metadata:**

[image]

**Email Body (Should say Anhui, not 110):**

[image]

**Update:**

We noticed that the List on the Form Designer has lost its Items during the upgrade. If we re-enter the Items in the Form Designer it works correctly.

**Form Designer - List in 7.5:**

[image]

**Form Designer - List in 8.1:**

[image]

Comment: In Sitecore 8.2.2, we're facing the exact other behavior (compared to your initially described problem and equal to your current behavior). We would love to have the value from the Select Box Options, but getting the text instead. Because otherwise the values wouldn't have no usage and we could go right away with the text values. Is there a wffm setting that controls the output of text vs. value?

Comment: Can you check the field item in the content editor if the reference is still there?

Comment: @JackJackson The problem was a bug with a Sitecore upgrade.

Comment: @adh thanks for the note. Please answer the question and include the support reference number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We noticed that the List on the Form Designer has lost its Items during the upgrade. If we re-enter the Items in the Form Designer it works correctly.

Form Designer - List in 7.5:

[image]

Form Designer - List in 8.1:

[image]